# condition not working in nested loop in php

Tags: php

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y <= 4; $y++) {
        if ($y == 0) {
            mysql_query("insert into tb_weight_rate_management 
                       (nation,zone_id,rate) values ('Domestic',1,'$del_100')");
        }
    }
}
```

hello i am little troubled using for loop....in the code above i have two loops ...1st loop will work 3 times and the the inside loop will work 4 times....
now when i click on submit button then it checks loop one and then enter second loop and inserts data 4 times in the database....which is wrong...i want if $y=0;
then it should insert data only once but it is inserting data 4 times can anyone please correct the above condition

Comment: Conditionnal equal is 2 = not 1

Comment: you must try `if($y == 0 )`

Comment: ohk but it is not working like that also i have tried it using ==

Comment: what is `y` doing here ? why are you creating a loop ? you just using `y` ONE TIME

Comment: this problem is solved..thnx guyss

Answer (score 1):

You should use `==` instead of `=`. Like this:

```
if ($y == 0) {
```

Comment: i did it but still it is inserting data 4 times

Comment: The first loop also has 4 iterations. (0,1,2,3)

Comment: Because there is 2 loops!

Answer (score 0):

the first loop runs 4 times, hence 4 inserts 
In the inner loop you declare $y = 0 on every iteration of the outer loop

Answer (score 0):

for each x iteration, there are one time y=0. and since x executes 4 times (0, 1, 2 and 3) y gets 0 value 4 times as well. if you want to do the insertion only once then you must add x value as well like if($y == 0 and x == 0).